# Inverse tSNE is feasible?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, word2vec, tsne

*Short question*: is it meaningful to use tSNE ( http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/t-SNE.html) to modify **existing** high-dimensional data using similarities in some *low-dimensional* vectors?
In essence, that means applying tSNE in *reverse* direction ( but with constraint, that we are **already given** high-dimensional vectors and just wanted to "deform" them using the information in low-dimensional vectors ).

*Long question*:
Here is my task : I have a list of word embeddings ( in word2vec sense ), and these vectors all are 64-dimensional.

On another hand, for each word a have another vector ( 15-dimensional ), and mapping is one-to-one ( i.e. each word have 64-dimensional embedding and 15-dimensional signature ). 15-dimensional vectors contain important additional information about words, which is impossible to take into account directly.

And I wanted to make these 64-dimensional vectors  more similar by taking into account similarity between corresponding 15-dimensional vectors.

Any advices in this direction are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the 15 dimensional vector to the 64 dimensional vector, obtaining a 79 dimensional vector. You can then reduce the dimensionality by projecting on eigensubspaces.

In general however, there are infinitely many ways to do this, so you need to come up with a way some sort of objective criterion for evaluating the quality of your embedding.

word2vec attempts to maximize the predictive ability of the embedding in skip-grams. What you could do is re-train word2vec, but using the 15 dimensional vectors as a side information in the network to predict the missing word.

Comment: Thanks, @Arthur B., I was thinking about this already, but many problems are in this direction, and normalization issues are most important of them ( 15-dims vectors contain very large numbers ( hundred millions )), plus entire concatenation operation doesn't look theoretically sound. But if we "deform" vectors using some side information, this at least look understandable ( i.e. we optimize KL divergence, after all ): in essence, we are doing something like kernel trick, no? And no pain with normalization...

Comment: Deform all you want, you still won't know by how much you should "deform" unless you tie this to some objective criterion.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. Why KL divergence ( which works in tSNE ) is not such a criterion to your opinion?! We just act like in basic t-SNE algorithm, but instead of initializing "learned" map with randoms, we initialize it with word2vec vectors. But t-SNE works if input dimensionality, say, 1000 dims and output is just 2d. Why will it break, if input is 15 dims and output is 64?

Comment: You can do that, but it's no less arbitrary than concatenation.

Comment: Ah, if I understood you right, you mean, that no operations on embedding ( be it concatenation, deformation, projection e t.c. ) are really meaningful because they don't add more information ( on contrary, retraining with side information is different, and thus more solid )? Yes? Honestly, I don't think, that whole idea of word2vec dimensions is solid enough :-) Because what these dimensions mean anyway?

Comment: They both add in information - from your 15 dimensional vectors - and remove information by deforming. You don't know if the balance is positive or negative.

Comment: Of course some options can sound reasonable. Doing PCA on the correlation matrix of the concatenated vectors is probably reasonable for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27238/discussion-between-vast-academician-and-arthur-b).